# MVC5 Cookie and same site problem with chrome

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, cookies, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to build an ECommerce with MVC5 with the following tools:
- Visual Studio 2017, Oracle DB 11g, Entity Framework 6, .NET Framework 4.6.2, I'm using https with a void certificate for testing. I'm creating my own cookies inside the application to save users choices and favorites items, I add items manually by removing the cookie and place the new updated one after every item added or removed by the customer, ever thing is okay on Firefox, but when I try to view the application from Chrome I got the following message:

> A cookie associated with a resource at http://localhost/ was set with `SameSite=None` but without `Secure`. It has been blocked, as Chrome now only delivers cookies marked `SameSite=None` if they are also marked `Secure`.

Here is my creation cookie code:

```cs
public HttpCookie CookieWareFromBrowser ()
{
    var ItemsCart = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Get(Models.StaticModels.CookiesManagedStrings.ItemsCart);    
    if (ItemsCart==null)
    {
        HttpCookie _ItemsCart = new HttpCookie(Models.StaticModels.CookiesManagedStrings.ItemsCart);


        _ItemsCart.Values.Add(Models.StaticModels.CookiesManagedStrings.Items, "|");                                       
        _ItemsCart.Values.Add(Models.StaticModels.CookiesManagedStrings.ItemsCount, "0");

        _ItemsCart.Expires = System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);

        HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Set(_ItemsCart);


        HttpContext.Current.Response.SetCookie(_ItemsCart);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush(); 

        return _ItemsCart;
    }
    ItemsCart.Expires = System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);

    return ItemsCart;
}
```

Adding item to cookie code :

```cs
public IHttpActionResult AddItemToCart(CartItem cartItem)
{
    var _cookie = new CookiesMaster().CookieWareFromBrowser();
    var Cookieitems = CookiesManagedStrings.decryptingCooki(_cookie.Values[CookiesManagedStrings.Items]);
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Cookieitems.Split('|').SingleOrDefault(s => s.Contains(cartItem.Id.ToString()))))

        _cookie.Values[CookiesManagedStrings.Items] = CookiesManagedStrings.encryptingCooki(Cookieitems + cartItem.Id + "," + cartItem.ProductName.Replace(",", "") + "," + cartItem.IValue + "," + cartItem.Quantity + "|");
    else
    {
        var item = Cookieitems.Split('|').Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)).SingleOrDefault(si => si.Contains(cartItem.Id.ToString()));
        var oldQty = int.Parse(item.Substring(item.LastIndexOf(',') + 1));
        var productbalance = _context.storage.Single(p => p.id== cartItem.Id && p.M_LOCATOR_ID == M_ProductManagedStrings.ID).FREE_BALANCE;

        if (productbalance >= oldQty + cartItem.Quantity)
        {
            var newItem = item.Substring(0, item.LastIndexOf(',') + 1) + (oldQty +cartItem.Quantity);

            Cookieitems = string.Join("|", Cookieitems.Split('|').Select(s => s.Replace(item, newItem)));
            _cookie.Values[CookiesManagedStrings.Items] = CookiesManagedStrings.encryptingCooki(Cookieitems);
        }
        else return BadRequest("Item Qty Exceeds Balance");
    }
    int x = 0;
    var v = CookiesManagedStrings.decryptingCooki(_cookie.Values[CookiesManagedStrings.ItemsCount]);
    if (int.TryParse(v, out x))
    {               
        _cookie.Values[CookiesManagedStrings.ItemsCount] = CookiesManagedStrings.encryptingCooki((int.Parse(v) + 1).ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        _cookie.Values[CookiesManagedStrings.ItemsCount] = CookiesManagedStrings.encryptingCooki(0.ToString());
    }
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Remove(CookiesManagedStrings.ItemsCart);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(_cookie);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Set(_cookie);

    return Ok(_cookie.Values[CookiesManagedStrings.ItemsCount]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

after many searches on the internet, I found two solutions 
A- adding the following in your web.config  if you use .netframe work less than 4.7.2

```
 <system.web>
<anonymousIdentification cookieRequireSSL="false" />
    <sessionState cookieSameSite="Lax" />
    <roleManager cookieRequireSSL="false" />   
    <authentication mode="None" />
</system.web>
```

B- if your using .net frame work higher than 4.6.2
you will fill the attribute samesite in your cookie by one of the following option according to your configuration :
Strict|Lax|None|Unspecified
or you can add to your web.config the following :

```
 <system.web>
  <httpCookies sameSite="[Strict|Lax|None|Unspecified]" requireSSL="[true|false]" />
 <system.web>
```